# Pass a list of filenames from a .txt to a find and copy command

Tags: linux, bash, find, sh, cp

I have a .txt file with a list of xml file names. 
I need to take each xml file and pair it to an image of the same name somewhere else in my directory.

I already use sed to clean the .xml from the file name

```
Text File Example:
 DF_0001.jpg.xml
 DF_0002.jpg.xml

 After 'sed' cleaning:
 DF_0001.jpg
 DF_0002.jpg

 Source File and Path Example:
 path/to/drive/1/DF0001.jpg
 path/to/drive/2/DF0002.jpg
```

My .txt file containing the xml file list is here. This is where the actual xml files are as well:

```
 /Sites/csv/file_list.txt
 /Sites/csv/DF_0001.jpg.xml
 /Sites/csv/DF_0002.jpg.xml
```

My image files (by the same name) live in any number of directories here:

```
 /Images/JPG/Day1/DF_0001.jpg
 /Images/JPG/Day1/DF_0002.jpg
 /Images/JPG/Day1/DF_0003.jpg
 /Images/JPG/Day2/DF0004.jpg
 /Images/JPG/Day2/DF0005.jpg
```

Simply put:
I need to find a .jpg file from a txt file, and move the corresponding xml to it.

Comment: Could you possibly be just a little bit more specific about your needs?

Comment: Sure... I have a list of xml files in a text document. They correspond to image files elsewhere in my directory. I'd like to step through that list of files, find the corresponding image and then move the xml to its same directory..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/\.xml//' /Sites/csv/file_list.xml > /tmp/your_jpg_files.txt
find /Images/JPG -type f -name "*.jpg" | grep -F -f /tmp/your_jpg_files.txt |
while read FILEPATH; do
    mv "/Sites/csv/${FILEPATH##*/}.xml" "${FILEPATH%/*}"
done
```

---

### Explanation:

```
sed 's/\.xml//' /Sites/csv/file_list.xml > /tmp/your_jpg_files.txt
```

Read the filenames from file_list.xml, remove the suffix .xml and save the result in a temp file.

---

```
find /Images/JPG -type f -name "*.jpg"
```

List all the paths to the .jpg files since the directory /Images/JPG

---

```
grep --fixed-strings --file=/tmp/your_jpg_files.txt
```

In the list of paths, you look the ones of your jpg files

---

```
while read FILEPATH; do
    mv "/Sites/csv/${FILEPATH##*/}.xml" "${FILEPATH%/*}"
done
```

At this step, you have all the paths to the .jpg files and for any of them, you'll make the **mv** you want.

`${FILEPATH##*/}` = `$(basename "$FILEPATH")` but more efficient.
`${FILEPATH%/*}` = `$(dirname "$FILEPATH")` but more efficient.

---

### Example

`FILEPATH` contains `/Images/JPG/Day2/DF0005.jpg`, so the actual `mv` will be:

```
# /Sites/csv/${FILEPATH##*/}.xml -> /Sites/csv/DF0005.jpg.xml
# ${FILEPATH%/*} -> /Images/JPG/Day2/
mv "/Sites/csv/DF0005.jpg.xml" "/Images/JPG/Day2/"
```

Comment: Incredible work @jaba10. Persistent and careful help. Couldn't have done it without you!!!

Answer (score 1):

The following is based on the assumption that you have no spaces neither in filenames nor in pathnames and that the xml file names are stored in a file named `"xmls"` (treating spaces in path/file names is probably simple but for sure it's tedious).

```
find . -type f -name '*.jpg' | while read a ; do 
    printf '%s ' `dirname "$a"`
    basename "$a"
done > jpegs
awk 'NR == FNR {tmp=$0;sub(".xml$","");xml[$0]=tmp;next}
    {if(xml[$2]) {print "cp ", xml[$2], $1 }}' xmls jpegs
```

The first command finds all the jpegs in the current and deeper directories, you can easily change that, and then feeds the pathnames to a pipeline that splits the path from the filename proper, the second one reads the `"xmls"` file to build an array of xml names indexed by the jpegs names and then processes the other file, printing a shell command if there is a match.

Comment: Having some problems with this one - the jpegs file is never written and so can't be referenced by awk. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: In my example, the file is written IFF `find` finds any .jpg file under the current directory, denoted by `"."` in the command line. If your .jpg  files are not under the current directory, you need to modify the command substituting `"."` with the correct starting point (from your example, it could be `/Images`).